# Vim-adventures on level 7 emptyStr = "xx xx";

Tags: vim-adventures

In earlier versions of vim-adventures I saw that the Puzzle was `emptyStr = "xxxxx"` which could be solved with either `fx -> dw` or `fx -> de`. However nowadays it seems to be a little different `emptyStr = "xx xx"`, which brings me to my question/problem:

How can I delete `xx xx` inside the quotes `"` as it is not one word anymore, with my given keystrokes shown in the pictures below?

Either I am missing something here or this might be a BUG...

[image: Puzzle]

[image: Keyboard]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can use the `d` command with any `{motion}`, see vim reference http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#d.

```
                                      *d*
["x]d{motion}       Delete text that {motion} moves over...
```

And a **motion** is explained here [http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#{motion}](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#%7Bmotion%7D) and can be `w`, `b`, `4j` or `t` etc.

Hint

> use `t` in combination

Solution

> complete solution is `fx -> dt"`

So it is definitely not a BUG as mentioned earlier.

Comment: Do you all-caps 'BUG' for some reason?

Comment: Ah sorry, not in particular, nothing to do with the "BUG"s from the game itself :).

Comment: I didn't realize there was Hint hidden with spoiler, but your answer pretty much gave me the answer. Thank you.